# Unable to communicate with process created with subprocess.Popen on solaris 10

Tags: python, subprocess, solaris-10

On linux, this will successfully change user's password.

```
subprocess.Popen('passwd', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=None)
subprocess.communicate(input='abc\nabc')
```

But on solaris, i found that after i invoke:

```
subprocess.Popen('iscsiadm modify -C iqn.xxx-xx.xxx', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,        stdout=None)
```

It will still show the "Enter Secret" prompt and ask for the password. And i can do nothing except inputing the password. Current shell still belongs to that iscsiadm process.

I need to wrapp this iscsiadm prompting for password and run it quietly. But now there seems to be something wrong here.

EDIT:
Why there are some programms implemented to accept input only from a terminal. As the example above, what's the difference between the linux passwd and solaris iscsiadm.

Comment: That command probably wants input from a terminal. Use [`pexpect`](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect), that uses a pseudo-terminal instead of a pipe.